# Why aren't icons centered?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make three buttons - arrow up, arrow down and comment button. For some reson i can't center the icons inside the buttons. Here is the code:

```css
.rate {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.rate img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
        <div class="rate"><img src="up.png"></div>
        <div class="rate"><img src="down.png"></div>
        <div class="rate"><img src="comment.png"></div>
```

So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: You need a `line-height` on `.rate`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol looks like it was too simple :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a fixed height to the image and use [relative positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Relative_positioning) to get the desired result.

```css
.rate {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rate img {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate">
  <img src="up.png">
</div>
<div class="rate">
  <img src="down.png">
</div>
<div class="rate">
  <img src="comment.png">
</div>
```

Comment: You're right, it could be adjusted to match the image height.. The `.rate` height is fixed at `30px` and without seeing the images or knowing the heights it's the best I could come up with..

Comment: @GCyrillus That's my fault, I didn't see the last bit of text below the snippet in the question. Your answer clearly explains *why* it's not working. +1

Answer (score 4):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) is your friend

```css
.rate {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rate img {
  width: 20px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100"></div>
<div class="rate"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100"></div>
<div class="rate"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100"></div>
```

**JSFidde Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kvm20oeb/**

Support: All modern browsers, IE11 and up. [source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: not exactly vertical centered though. it must a little lower

Comment: and it can be fixed with `height:20px` to img tags

Comment: Thanks it works, but will it work in older browsers?

Comment: line-height will do the job for dinosaurus and latest browser :)

Comment: hmm.. the placeholder's fault then :/

Answer (score 2):

Because your image are standing on the baseline. Defaut, when not reset, is 1em (average 16px in most browser defaut setting).

So you have approximatively  a line-height of 16px where sits your image + 14px remainings below.

If you set a line-height to 30px, it will set the minimal height of your coontainer (1 line) and image will sit there.

The 101 way before playing with BFC is a line-height equal to height and it will do the job here with no fuss.

---

*(you can remove height, line-height should size the element height since there is a single line ... hmm you mention older browser: so IE5.5/IE6 might bug and increase height a little more than 30px ... for the others no troubles )*

```css
.rate {
  display: inline-block;
  /*height: 30px;*/
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rate img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/20x20&text=↑">
</div>
<div class="rate">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/20x20&text=↓">
</div>
<div class="rate">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/20x20&text=♥">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man this is a great solution since i think flexbox will work only in the new browsers

Answer (score 0):

```
.rate img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      }
```